# Preimage of a primary $\mathfrak{p}$-ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $\varphi:R\to R'$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq R'$ be a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary ideal of $R'$. Is the preimage $\varphi^{-1}({\mathfrak{q}})$ a $\varphi^{-1}({\mathfrak{p}})$-primary ideal?

Denote $\mathfrak{p}^c=\varphi^{-1}({\mathfrak{p}})$. Of course, $\mathfrak{p}^c$ is a prime ideal. Also, we can look at the induced map $\bar{\varphi}:R/{\mathfrak{q}^c}\to R'/\mathfrak{q}$, to obtain that it is injective, and therefore every zero divisor in $R/{\mathfrak{q}^c}$ is nilpotent. Hence ${\mathfrak{q}^c}$ is primary, but I don't see why would it be a $\mathfrak{p}^c$-primary ideal.

Comment: The proof is straight forward with the definitions. You need to verify that the radical of $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ is the preimage of the radical of $\mathfrak{q}$. Please try it and show your progress.

Comment: That is part of Theorem $14$, Chapter $3$ in Zariski's *Commutative Algebra*, the first volume (GTM$28$). Though the proof is omitted on the book, as the author commented, the proof is immediate from Theorem $13$. (However, you do not need to hesitate to ask for details if you are still struck.)